# Too many arguments in imwarp Matlab (imregister)

Tags: image, matlab, registration

I am trying to register a pair of endoscopic images but I cannot because I get the following error:

```
Error using imwarp Too many input arguments.

Error in imregister2 (line 145) [movingReg,Rreg] = imwarp(moving,Rmoving,tform,'OutputView',Rfixed);
```

I am not doing anything strange in my code, just load the images and perform the registration:

```
 im1 = imread('./Seq05/Seq05_50.bmp');  
 im2 = imread('./Seq05/Seq05_51.bmp'); 
 figure, imshowpair(rgb2gray(im2), rgb2gray(im1), 'montage')
 title('Unregistered') 
 [optimizer, metric] = imregconfig('multimodal');
 moving_reg = imregister2(rgb2gray(im1),rgb2gray(im2),'affine',optimizer,metric);
```

Any idea why this is happening? It is quite important. Thank you very much in advance.

Antonio.

Comment: Try `which imwarp` and check that MATLAB is finding the correct version of the function.

Comment: where did you get that imregister2? You might want to use imregtform and then imwarp if you can.